# In non-euclidean geometry, can hypotenus of rightangle triangle be shorter than sides?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, spherical-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

**Disclaimer.** This is only a recreational question in geometry...

---

In euclidean geometry, the following picture is definitely inconsistent!

[image]

Of course, the issue is that, the picture suggests that the diagonal is *at most* as long as the sides, i.e $\mathbf{\sqrt{2} \le 1}$ (a contradiction!).

> **Question (loose).** *Is there a (necessarily non-euclidean) geometry in which the picture would be consistent ?*

### Noneuclidean geometry

To make sense of the above question, one needs to first extend certain euclidean geometry. Viz

- A straight line is a geodesic curve.
- Two straight lines $\mathcal L_1$ and $\mathcal L_2$ are perpendicular at a point $A$ if their tangents at $A$ are perpendicular
- A square $ABCD$ of side length $L$ is a quadruple of four lines (i.e geodesic curves!) $AB,BC,CD,DA$ such that

  - **Perpendicular sides.** $AB \perp BC$ at $B$, $BC \perp CD$ at $C$, and $CD \perp DA$ at $D$, $DA \perp AB$ at $A$.
  - **Equal side lengths.** $\ell(AB) = \ell(BC) = \ell(CD) = \ell(DA) = L$.

The diagonals of a square are the straight lines (i.e geodesics) $AC$ and $BD$.

**Question (refined).** *Is there geometry (i.e smooth riemannian manifold) in which there exists a square of side length $L$ both of whose diagonals have (equal) length which is $L$ or less ?*

Comment: There is no "th" in "hypotenuse". It's spelled like this. Maybe you mix it up with "hypothesis", but that is a different Greek word (both contain "hypo-" meaning "under-", but the following verb is different.)

Comment: Great to know, thanks!

Comment: With the refinement to your question, there's a new problem: a (uniform) geometry in which squares — under your definition — exist _is_ Euclidean! One can speak of equilateral right triangles in spherical geometry (the 'octant' triangle), and equilateral right pentagons (or hexagons, etc.) in hyperbolic geometry, but an equilateral right-angled quadrilateral implies a Euclidean space.

Comment: Hum, interesting. By "uniform", do you mean "isotropic", in the sense that the volume element is position-independent ?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Also please feel free to propose a modification of the question for which only solutions are "nontrivial" geometries :)

Comment: I don't think it is possible for any 2D plane, the sides must completely overlay with the diagonals to make L(side)=diagonal which means on an extreme saddle diagonals are still slightly longer than sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hypotenuse by definition is the longest side in a right triangle (which is opposite the right angle). In flat geometry, such triangles can have only one right angle, hence only one hypotenuse.

In geometries where the sum of angles in a triangle is less than $180°,$ there will also be one hypotenuse. However, in geometries where the sum of the angles exceeds this value, then there may well be more than one hypotenuse. Also, since in this kind of geometry, a triangle may be simultaneously right-angled and obtuse angled, then **it is possible for a side to be longer than each of the sides opposite the right angle. Thus this answers your question in the positive.** However such questions are already moot here since the Pythagorean theorem doesn't hold, so what's the point of defining hypotenuses same as they are defined in flat geometry, where they are singled out there because of their importance and the many relationships they reveal?

---

OK, I've read the edited question, and the germ of the answer is contained in the above answer -- I'll highlight this. Your question is equivalent to asking if there exist geometries where an isosceles triangle with only one right angle (where the angle is contained between the equal legs) has the base not more than the equal legs. Again, the answer is that that happens in some geometry where the angle sum in triangles is more than $180°,$ for then we would have a case where the base angles are equal to or more than $90°$ each, which would make the legs of the triangle be equal to or even exceed that of the side opposite the unique right angle.

Comment: @Allwonder Thanks for the input. Some clarification. Forget about the term "hypothenus" as defined in usually in geometry. I've given my own definition in the question. By "hypothenus", I mean the diagonals in ABCD, i.e the coords AC and BD. My use of the term in the question title was only to draw attention. In fact, there is no mention of "triangle" in the body of my question :)

Comment: @dohmatob I didn't see the attached image before. Did you just add it? Also, it seems the question has been largely edited now. Am I right? I'll read it again though and see what comes to me.

Comment: @Allawonda No, the image was always there. The question is not largely edited I just changed all instances of "hypothenus" to "diagonal", to be more explicit.

Comment: @dohmatob OK. That must have been the network or device then. I've now edited my answer.

Comment: OK great, this confirms what I thought: there exist positively curved curved manifolds with large squares that have this property!

Comment: @dohmatob Be careful with your assumptions. In a sphere (which is a positively curved manifold), if 4 sides are of equal length and the angles are equal, then the angles must be greater than right angles, so a square as you might be trying to imagine it doesn't exist.

Comment: @MarkS. Such things need not exist in every non-euclidean geometry. The point is that it is possible for such to exist.